# How can I count the number of a letter in a string using Dart?

Tags: string, dart, contains, counting

I'm trying to calculate how many of the letter `a` I have in the sentence: `Hello Jordania`.

I found the function `contains()`. I'm using it like this:

```
var phrase = "Hello Jordania";
var comptenbrdea = phrase.contains('a');
print(comptenbrdea);
```

As we know, I got `True` as a response. I couldn't find the right function to calculate **how many** times I get an `a`. I might be able to do something with a loop if I can check every single character? I'm lost on [this](http://www.dartlang.org/search.html?cx=011220921317074318178%3Ai4mscbaxtru&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&q=string_scanner).

Comment: nuclear option: use regex to remove everything that ISN'T an `a`, then get the length of whatever remains.

Comment: I find thise function : Map<String, int> letterFrequency(String text) {
    String textWoutSpaces = text.replaceAll('\n', '').
        replaceAll(' ', '').replaceAll('.', '');
    List charList = textWoutSpaces.splitChars();
    charList.sort((m,n) => m.compareTo(n));
    var charMap = {};
    for (var char in charList) {
      if(char == 'o'){
      charMap[char] = charMap.putIfAbsent(char, () => 0) + 1;
      }
}
    return charMap;
  }

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```dart
void main() {
  print('a'.allMatches('Hello Jordania').length); // 2
}
```

Edit: the tested string is the parameter, not the character to be counted.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working, then I realized that I had switched the equivalent of `'a'` and `'Hello Jordania'` for my use case. The correct order of putting the pattern first and the thing to search inside `allMatches` seems backwards to me.

Comment: Got bitten by this as well. Thanks for your comment @LukeHutchison which helped me to solve this immediately.

Answer (score 6):

```
void main() {
  const regExp = const RegExp("a");
  print(regExp.allMatches("Hello Jordania").length); // 2
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void main(){
  String str = "yours string";
  Map<String, int> map = {};
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    int count = map[str[i]] ?? 0;
     map[str[i]] = count + 1;
  }
  print(map);
}
```

Comment: Add explanations to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate on the characters and count them, you comment above contains a general function for building a histogram, but the version that just counts 'a's is probably good for you to write. I'll just show you how to loop over characters:

```
var myString = "hello";
for (var char in myString.splitChars()) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best one, but you can also do something like this.

```
void main() {
  var a = "ht://adfd//.coma/";

  int count = a.split("t").length - 1;
  print(count);
}
```

You will need to subtract 1 because it is splitting into a list first and then counting the size of that list.

Answer (score -1):

```
  // count letters
  Map<int,int> counts = new Map<int,int>();
  for (var c in s.charCodes() ) {
    counts[c] = counts.putIfAbsent(c, p()=>0) + 1;
  }
  // print counts
  for (var c in counts.getKeys())
    print("letter ${new String.fromCharCodes([c])} count=${counts[c]}");
```